# Rspec3: Send an Exception to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I want to test my controller and make sure it renders the proper template whenever it receives an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

The controller:

```
class QuestionnaireController < ApplicationController

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :verses_not_found

  def poem
    @questionnaire = JSON.parse(session[:questionnaire], symbolize_names: true)
    rawVerses = VerseSelector.select_verses(@questionnaire[:trait_category], @questionnaire[:message_category])
    @poem = PoemCustomizer.customize_poem(rawVerses, @questionnaire)
  end

  def verses_not_found
    render 'questionnaire/verses_not_found'
  end
end
```

My test:

```
describe "GET 'poem'" do
  it "renders questionnaire/verses_not_found.html if theres an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception" do
    verse_selector = double("VerseSelector", select_verses: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.new("Verses not found"))
    get 'poem', nil, {questionnaire: {receiver_name:"a",location:"b",relationship:"coach",trait_category:"adventurous venturous",message_category:"You hurt my feelings"}}.to_json
    expect(response).to render_template(:verses_not_found)
  end
end
```

I'm not sure at all about my test, which currently raises an error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for #<String:0xbcdf388>`

How to write my test properly?

Comment: I'd stub poem to raise RecordNotFound and then test to see if verses_not_found was received when calling poem myself. Then another test to see if the latter method rendered the correct page.

Comment: I'd create an anonymous action that raise RecordNotFound and get that action to verify that the expected template is rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to simulate an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` with the following code:

```
it "renders questionnaire/verses_not_found.html if theres an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception" do
  verse_selector = double("verse_selector")
  allow(verse_selector).to receive(:select_verses).and_return(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.new())
  get 'poem', nil, {"questionnaire" => {"receiver_name"=> "a","location"=> "b","relationship"=> "coach","trait_category"=> "adventurous venturous","message_category"=> "You hurt my feelings"}.to_json}
  expect(response).to render_template(:verses_not_found)
end
```